# How to delete all the worskpace that are mapped to a physical folder in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am using TFS 2013.

What would a command to Delete All the WorkSpace belonging to any Agent that is mapped to a specific folder look like?

For Example all the Workspace that are mapped to "C:\ABC\Common" should be deleted.

Want to add script as pre build Task

Answer (score 0):

I would use the (free) tool TFS Sidekicks to do this.  You can easily view all the workspaces for that computer/agent, and see the mappings for each one.  Also you can easily delete all the relevant workspaces from the tool in a nice GUI.

http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

[image]

Comment: Looking for script to be run as pre build task